# Finding grease pencil erasers via python in 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil

I'm writing a script to index through the grease pencil brushes but I would like to filter out eraser brushes. I can determine if the brush is used for grease pencil by `bpy.data.brushes[0].use_paint_grease_pencil` but I can't find how to determine if it is a grease pencil eraser.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `gpencil_tool` property of the `brush` object.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Brush.html?highlight=gpencil_tool#bpy.types.Brush.gpencil_tool), it will contain one of these options:

> - `DRAW` Draw, The brush is of type used for drawing strokes.
> - `FILL` Fill, The brush is of type used for filling areas.
> - `ERASE` Erase, The brush is used for erasing strokes.

So you can make sure you only access `DRAW` brushes by using this `if` statement in your loop:

```
if brush.gpencil_tool == "DRAW":
    #Do something
```